# dynamic textbox and save to database in c#.net

Tags: c#

i have a backend where an administrator will store a value suppose 10. i want to populate 10 dropdown dynamically and save it to the database.

**here is the codes but i've hardcoded it.**

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="student_project_choice.aspx.cs" Inherits="Final_Year_Project_Allocation_System.student_project_choice" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
        <div class="well">
            <div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Choice number
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Project titles
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Demand
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                    AutoPostBack="True">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UomDBConnectionString1 %>" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_lecturer_project]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                             </asp:ScriptManager>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>  
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDemand" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/></Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                2
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                3
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                4
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                5
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                6
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                7
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                8
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                9
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                                                <tr>
                            <td>
                                10
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="projectTitle" 
                                    DataValueField="lecturerProjectId">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group controls">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                <input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Content>
```

please give me some ideas how can i achieve this.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace Final_Year_Project_Allocation_System
{
    public partial class student_project_choice : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UomDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
                string selectSQL = "select Count(choiceNumber) from tbl_student_project_choice where choiceProjectId = '" + selected + "' and choiceNumber='"+1+"'";
                // Define the ADO.NET objects.
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
                int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                lblDemand.Text = result.ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception exce)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = exce.Message;
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is your actual question here and where are you having and or seeing issues..? what does your code behind look like Rees? also if you are only storing one value in the list why are you doing this `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_lecturer_project]` I would recommend looking at using a `BindingList<>` also what do all 10 dropdown boxes have in common how is this data related..?

Comment: i want to create those drop down dynamically based on a number. if i store 15 in my database it should show create 15 drop down.

Comment: To expand on what DJ KRAZE is asking, we very much would need to see the code behind in order to effectively help you.  What you have posted just shows us the layout of your page.

Comment: That's more understandable have you thought about using a Repeater ? also this can be done but you would have to take into account the location `X,Y` Coordinates as well I am sure this can be accomplished with a repeater

Comment: i want to create those 10 drop down based from database thats all. here there is no codes creating those dropdown dynamically.

Comment: you need to write the code and something like this Reese
`DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
       ddl.ID = "DropDownList1";
       ddl.DataSource = "Array or List<> etc..."
       ddl.DataBind();` you need to build the ddl.ID based on the ddl.ID = "DropDownList" + i" for example which means you will need a for loop